# Saving entries on different tables fails sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, graphql

I am new to Rails, I want to save an entry to **table A** that table generates a new id when the creation is done, I need to use that fresh id to create a new entry on **table B**.

At the moment my current solutions just work sometimes, what happens is that the id is strictly necessary to create the entry on **table B** and my guess is that the entry on **table A** is not yet saved when I try to create a new entry on **table B**.

**Below is the code** that I am using to accomplish the behavior above:

```
class Resolvers::CreateTask < GraphQL::Function
  argument :name, !types.String
  argument :organization, !types.String

  type Types::TaskType

  def call(_obj, args, ctx)  
    task = Task.create!(
      name: args[:name],
    )

    TaskOrganization.create!(
      task_id: task.id
      organization: args[:organization]
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: What is `task_id` in `Task`?

Comment: I edited, the task id is the id of the previous task created on the Task table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one-to-one association between `Task` and `TaskOrganization`, In `Task` model, add this line

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :task_organization
```

If it is one-to-many pluralize it, `:task_organizations`

Then do this in `call` method above

```
def call(_obj, args, ctx)  
  task = Task.create!(
    name: args[:name],
    task_organization_attributes: { organization: args[:organization] }
  )
end
```

Give it a try!